# How to create a query to prompt for and create a number of new columns to its result?

Tags: sql, ms-access, multiple-columns

For example, I have a student register query. If a particular module has 3 sessions, the query should prompt me how many sessions and when i type 3, three new columns should appear in its result.

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT Mid(([firstname]),1) & " " & Mid(([surname]),1) AS Name, 
tbl_trainers.Ministry, "_______________" AS [Day 1]
FROM tbl_trainers 
INNER JOIN (tbl_sessions INNER JOIN tbl_trainer_sessions 
  ON tbl_sessions.session_id = tbl_trainer_sessions.SessionID) 
  ON tbl_trainers.trainerid = tbl_trainer_sessions.TrainerID
WHERE (((tbl_sessions.session_id)=[From Session ID]))
ORDER BY tbl_trainers.Ministry, tbl_sessions.session_id;
```

Comment: You need to add some context, it's hard to know what this is about. Look for some tags that are relevant to whatever technology you're using.

Comment: Trying to make a simple query using MS Access 2007. We have a Training Database here that generates session attendance registers.

Comment: This is what I have so far...                                                                                                       SELECT Mid(([firstname]),1) & " " & Mid(([surname]),1) AS Name, tbl_trainers.Ministry, "_______________" AS [Day 1]
FROM tbl_trainers INNER JOIN (tbl_sessions INNER JOIN tbl_trainer_sessions ON tbl_sessions.session_id = tbl_trainer_sessions.SessionID) ON tbl_trainers.trainerid = tbl_trainer_sessions.TrainerID
WHERE (((tbl_sessions.session_id)=[From Session ID]))
ORDER BY tbl_trainers.Ministry, tbl_sessions.session_id;

Comment: added some tags for you so the question will get shown to people familiar with this. add the details in the comment to your question so they're more legible.

Comment: Queries can create columns based on existing data pretty easily.  You can also have a query that prompts the user for information, and uses that information in a filter.  However, I don't think you can do what your asking in a direct query.  You can do it in VBA code that can be launched from an event (say, on page load or on button click), is it absolutely necessary that it's done in a query?